# Renaming files in directory

Tags: javascript, php

Hey Guys I got huge amout .mp3 files in my server directory that are used for playing music, most of files unfortunately look like this : (Artist_-_SongName).
Is it possible to create script in php or js that will take all files in directory and delete in them ' _ ' sign and leave space ? I will be really gratefull for help!

Comment: Yes, it *is* possible. Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: @PiotrSikora Glad the answer helped, feel free to accept the answer

Comment: @PiotrSikora Just a note on StackOverflow...it's generally good practice to accept answers. You have 7 questions all with answer, waiting for accepting. It helps other users find solutions to similar questions, as well as rewarding those who take the time to help the OP ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this...

```
foreach (glob('*.mp3') as $filename) {
    rename($filename, str_replace('_', '', $filename));
}
```

Comment: Very neat solution.

Comment: But that would replace _ in the extension as well in the case you have a different filter like '*.mp_3'

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by looping through your directory and using `str_replace()` and `rename()`:

```
<?php 
# IgnoreFiles
$IgnoreFiles = array(".","..","Thumbs.db");

# define your directory
$MP3Directory = "your-directory";

# get directory files
$MP3Files = scandir($MP3Directory);

# loop through the files
foreach($MP3Files as $MP3File){
    # make sure the file isn't in the "ignore" array
    if(!in_array($MP3File, $IgnoreFiles)){
        # get file details
        $MP3Details = pathinfo($MP3Directory."\\".$MP3File);
        # make sure file extension is mp3
        if(strtolower($MP3Details['extension']) == "mp3"){
            # find/replace
            $NewFileName = str_replace("_"," ",$MP3File);
        }
        # rename file
        rename($MP3Directory."\\".$MP3File, $MP3Directory."\\".$NewFileName);
    }
}    
?>
```

Comment: @PiotrSikora Glad to help, feel free to accept the answer ;)